# Modifying format of rows values in Pandas Data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, row

I have a dataset of 70000+ data points (see picture)

[image: dataframe]

As you can see, in the column 'date' half of the format is different (more messy) compared to the other half (more clear). How can I make the whole format as the second half of my data frame?

I know how to do it manually, but it will take ages!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(x)) / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') if str(x).isdigit() else x)
```

Date is in a strange format

[[image: STRANGE DATE]

**EDIT 2**

two data formats:

- 2012-01-01 00:00:00
- 2020-07-21T22:45:00+00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the below and it works, note that this assuming two key assumptions:

**1-** Your date fromat follows one and ONLY ONE of the TWO formats in your example!

**2-** The final output is a string!

If so, this should do the trick, else, it's a starting point and can be altered to you want it to look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#data sample
d = {'date':['20090602123000', '20090602124500', '2020-07-22 18:45:00+00:00', '2020-07-22 19:00:00+00:00']}

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
print(df)

                        date
0             20090602123000
1             20090602124500
2  2020-07-22 18:45:00+00:00
3  2020-07-22 19:00:00+00:00

#loop over records
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #get date
    dateString = df.at[i,'date']
    #check if it's the undesired format or the desired format
    #NOTE i'm using the '+' substring to identify that, this comes to my first assumption above that you only have two formats and that should work
    if '+' not in dateString:
        #reformat datetime
        #NOTE: this is comes to my second assumption where i'm producing it into a string format to add the '+00:00'
        df['date'].loc[df.index == i] = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) + '+00:00'
    else:
        continue

print(df)

                        date
0  2009-06-02 12:30:00+00:00
1  2009-06-02 12:45:00+00:00
2  2020-07-22 18:45:00+00:00
3  2020-07-22 19:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, no I haven't, how would you use them?

Comment: These are hyperlinks, you can follow the link to a detailed explanation of the two functions which hopefully should be clear, if you still can't work it out, let me know!

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to follow the hyperlinks but I did not get any good result. if you would like to have a try, let me know how it goes!

Comment: Sure, can you please add a reproducible sample of the data into your question? Ideally few rows from both end of the df.

Comment: thanks, i've already replicated few rows and have now modified the answer, note this is not the most efficent way however it does the job for now. Let me know should there be an issue.

Comment: Also, note that time is different between the two format dates, but It not a problem, I just want to set all in the same format., thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that, there's a big gap for improving run time on this approach but i'll leave that to you to play with if needs be.

Comment: Thanks @Mit. Last thing: I have also another similar data frame with two different date formats (see edit2). I have tried to implement your code but I get error  - ValueError: time data '2012-01-01 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'.  Is there a way to adapt your code?

Comment: yes, for the second df, change the format in the strptime from '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' to '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Absolutely amazing, thanks for the effort. I have also another kind of coding task that I am struggling with and it relates to LSTM. If you'd like to have a look, I can share my code on colab with you. Otherwise, very much appreciated your help here!

Comment: Now quite sure what LSTM is, but if you run into issues feel free to post your questions here and i’m sure the community will help! You can tag me in the question and i can look into it.

Comment: Thank you @Mit, I will post it. And super grateful for the existence of this amazing community #stackoverflow

Comment: I have revised my question and made it as minimal as possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072905/differencing-transform-technique. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

you can format the first part of your dataframe

```
import datetime as dt
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(x)) / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') if str(x).isdigit() else x)
```

this checks if all characters of the value are digits, then format the date as the second part

**EDIT**

the timestamp seems to be in miliseconds while they should be in seconds => `/ 1000`

Comment: Thanks!, but I get this error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: I have converted to integer < df['date'].astype(int) >, but then I get this other error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Comment: @Jack_T I've edited it to convert the timestamp first to str then to int

Comment: Thanks, but now I get a value error -  ValueError: year 638916 is out of range

Comment: Is there a way to check if a value in my date column perhaps is not in date format? thanks

Comment: @Jack_T maybe your timestamp values are in miliseconds while it should be in seconds, try adding a division by 1000 and see if it fits your date ranges

Comment: I have tried by using only the first 1000 datapoints (in format - 20100104103000) and I get the same error < year 638916 is out of range >. I have also tried with the latest 1000 datapoints (in format - 2020-07-22 18:45:00+00:00) and I get this error < AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'isdigit' >. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jack_T the first error is because the timestamps are in miliseconds, I've divided by 1000 to correct it, and for the second I had to convert x to str in order to apply `isdigit()`

Comment: Thanks, it worked somehow but now I am getting strange dates (see edit)

Comment: @Jack_T There may be an error in the data, I've checked using hard coded value and it gives dates aroud year 2606

Comment: Oh maybe I know what the error might be. While the 'year-month-day' format is okay for the entire dataset (from 2010-01-01 till 2020-07-22), the time is actually different: for the data with format (20100104103000) the time ranges from 10:30 till 17:00 in 15 mins shape. For the date with format (2020-07-22 18:45:00+00:00), the time ranges from 14:30 till 21:00 in 15 mins. Hence, both have shape in 15 mins and also 6 and half hours of data, but their range is different. Do you think this might be the problem? thanks again for your help and time.